# Summation in a datatable column

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

Here is my code in my view

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api(), data;

            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };

            // Total over all pages
            total = api
                .column( 4 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );

            // Total over this page
            pageTotal = api
                .column( 4, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );

            // Update footer
            $( api.column( 4 ).footer() ).html(pageTotal);
        }
    } );
} );
```

I'm making use of this [DataTables example](https://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html), and I can't seem to get how did he did it and mine is not working.

Here is the picture of the program that I'm doing:

[image: program]

Hope someone can teach me... I've just started CI so i'm still learning.

Comment: What is happening? Errors in the console? Did you include jQuery?

Comment: there is no error and i already included this <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')?>"></script> JQuey

Comment: it still running but nothings happening in my code. i

Comment: I guess you are not having a `<tfoot>` section, if you not have one you are just injecting the summary into nothing ...

Comment: i have my <tfoot> its the total in the picture

Comment: Including jquery.datatables is not enough. Before that you need to also include the standard jQuery lib.

Comment: what library should i download @trincot can you give me a link please

Comment: You could use this one: `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js`.

Comment: im using this tho jquery-2.2.0.js

Comment: I included the library you suggested still not working. Are you in GitHub? do you want to check the whole program?

Comment: Make a fiddle on JS fiddle.

Comment: wait what i dont know fiddle is.

Comment: one last question do you have other alternative that you can suggest??

Comment: Put your code on http://jsfiddle.net/: JS, HTML and CSS parts. Make sure to include the script tags for including the libraries in the HTML part. Run and check, then pass the link, and we will check.

Comment: sir I use codeigniter im using MVC @trincot

Comment: Yes, but your problem is not related to CodeIgniter (or PHP for that matter), so you should extract a working example that concentrates only on the problem (the datatable). But listen, I don't have much time, so I am moving on.

Comment: okay ill extract @trincot just comment "let's do it" when your online already thanks..... I'll be waiting.. I really can't make it to work.